# Tomcat 7.0.35 won't start in Server 2008 R2

Tags: tomcat

I am having problems starting/running 64-bit Tomcat on Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) with 64-bit JRE installed.

**What I have installed:**
(on Server 2008 R2 64-bit)

Tomcat 7.0.35 (64-bit version), unzipped to top level of C:\ so C:\tomcat contains all the Tomcat directories ie bin, conf, lib etc...

jre-7u11 (64-bit version) installed into C:\Program Files by running the exe

**What I have done:**

```
set CATALINA_HOME environment (user) variable to C:\tomcat

set JAVA_HOME system variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

**What I have tried** (didn't work):
setting **JRE**_HOME system variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

using shorthand for the path ie:

> C:\Progra~1\Java\jre7

to get rid of the whitespace

**What happens:**
On double-clicking the `C:\tomcat\bin\startup.bat` file, a cmd window momentarily opens, then immediately closes. 
I added PAUSE to the bottom of startup.bat, and the output is as follows:

'Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined. At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program'

**My question:**
Have i not correctly set the JAVA_HOME environment variable? 
(setting the JRE_HOME environment variable doesn't work either)

also - there is nothing in the tomcat\logs folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where did you set these variables?

If you defined them in a console prompt, have you tried running c:\tomcat\bin\startup.bat from the same prompt that you set your variables? My guess is that the double clicking starts a new environment which doesn't see the variables set (in another environment)

You can right-click "My Computer" > Properties > Advanced > Environment variables, to add JAVA_HOME to System variables, after this step is done try it again. Changing variables cannot affect running processes and incoming child processes.

Comment: Thanks @Yogi, that worked! I didn't think of running startup.bat from a cmd prompt - but I **was** closing down all cmd windows before double-clicking on startup.bat, yet the tomcat still wasn't starting up.